# TSQL: how do i show 0.00 totals for this column

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a Department table with 15 different departments.  I want my query to show some totals for a certain project.  In this particular project there are 3 departments that are working on it and have totals for various things.  My current query does show the totals for those three departments.  However, i also want to show all the other departments but just have zeros in the totals columns for those departments.  Those departments did not have anything to do with this project but still need to show them with zero totals. Here is my query that results in three rows of data. **Disciplines** is the table with all my departments.  **Project_Disciplines** are those that are actually working on the project

```
SELECT   
T.NAme
,ISNULL(CAST(t.EngHours AS DECIMAL(15,0)),0) AS EngHours
,ISNULL(SUM(t.EngBlendedRate),0) as EngRate
,ISNULL(CAST(t.EngHours * SUM(t.EngBlendedRate) AS DECIMAL(15,0)),0) AS EngDollars
,ISNULL(CAST(t.DesignHours AS DECIMAL(15,0)),0) AS DesignHours
,ISNULL(sum(t.DsgBlendedRate),0) AS DesignRate
,ISNULL(CAST(t.DesignHours * SUM(t.DsgBlendedRate) AS DECIMAL(15,0)),0) AS DesignDollars
,ISNULL(t.EngHours + t.DesignHours,0) AS TotalHours
,ISNULL(CAST(CAST((t.EngHours * SUM(t.EngBlendedRate))  + (t.DesignHours * SUM(t.DsgBlendedRate)) AS DECIMAL (18,2)) / CAST(NULLIF(t.EngHours + t.DesignHours,0) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS DECIMAL (18,2)),0)  AS TotalRate
,CAST(ISNULL((t.EngHours * SUM(t.EngBlendedRate)),0)  + ISNULL((t.DesignHours * SUM(t.DsgBlendedRate)),0) AS DECIMAL(15,0)) AS TotalDollars
,ISNULL(MAX(case when OA.Code = 'Travel' then OA.Cost end),0) Travel
,ISNULL(MAX(case when OA.Code = 'Equipment' then OA.Cost end),0) Equipment
,ISNULL(MAX(case when OA.Code = 'Subcontract' then OA.Cost end),0) Subcontract
,ISNULL(MAX(case when OA.Code = 'Other' then OA.Cost end),0) Other
,ISNULL(MAX(case when OA.Code = 'Markups' then OA.Cost end),0) Markups
,CAST(ISNULL((t.EngHours * SUM(t.EngBlendedRate)),0)  + ISNULL((t.DesignHours * SUM(t.DsgBlendedRate)),0) AS DECIMAL(15,0)) 
+ ISNULL(MAX(case when OA.Code = 'Travel' then OA.Cost end),0)
+ ISNULL(MAX(case when OA.Code = 'Equipment' then OA.Cost end),0)
+ ISNULL(MAX(case when OA.Code = 'Subcontract' then OA.Cost end),0)
+ ISNULL(MAX(case when OA.Code = 'Other' then OA.Cost end),0)
+ ISNULL(MAX(case when OA.Code = 'Markups' then OA.Cost end),0) AS EstimateTotal

FROM

(SELECT c.id, x.Name, 
ISNULL(CASE WHEN f.team_type_id = 1 OR f.team_type_id = 3
THEN
CAST(f.POH * (d.HourlyRate * (1-(r.Discount/100))/100) AS DECIMAL(8,2))
END,0) AS EngBlendedRate ,
ISNULL(CASE WHEN f.team_type_id = 2 OR f.team_type_id = 4
THEN
ISNULL(CAST(f.POH * (d.HourlyRate * (1-(r.Discount/100))/100) AS DECIMAL(8,2)),0) END,0) AS DsgBlendedRate
,ISNULL(CAST(SUM((b.qty * b.unit_rate)* b.Eng_RPQ /100) AS DECIMAL(8,1)),0) AS [EngHours]
,ISNULL(CAST(SUM((b.qty * b.unit_rate)* b.Design_RPQ /100) AS DECIMAL(8,1)),0) AS [DesignHours]
FROM Project p 
INNER JOIN Project_Disciplines pd on p.id = pd.project_id
INNER JOIN Discipline x on x.id = pd.Disc_id
INNER JOIN Activity c on c.discipline_id = x.id
INNER JOIN Activity_Details b ON b.activity_id = c.id
INNER JOIN Team f on f.activity_id = c.id
INNER JOIN SOF_Details d on d.id = f.sof_detail_id
INNER JOIN Rate r on r.projectid = p.id 
WHERE p.id = 19 
GROUP BY  c.id, x.Name, 
f.team_type_id
, f.POH,d.HourlyRate,r.Discount
) AS T 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT a.activity_id, c.Code
,CAST(Sum(a.Rate * a.Qty)AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS COST

FROM Other_Activity a
INNER JOIN Activity b on a.activity_id = b.id
INNER JOIN EXPENSE_Codes c on a.expense_code_id = c.id
WHERE b.project_id = 19

GROUP BY a.activity_id, c.Code) AS OA ON OA.activity_id = T.id

GROUP BY  T.Name, t.EngHours, t.DesignHours
```

**Results**

```
NAme    EngHours    EngRate EngDollars  DesignHours DesignRate  DesignDollars   TotalHours  TotalRate   TotalDollars    Travel  Equipment   Subcontract Other   Markups EstimateTotal
Architechtural  81  110.73  8947    237 78.85   18711   318.1   86.95   27658   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    27658.00
Concrete    3014    423.72  1277092 2136    357.96  764603  5150.0  396.45  2041695 60.00   45.00   0.00    325.00  0.00    2042125.00
Structural  903 104.98  94744   1351    0.00    0   2253.0  42.05   94744   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    94744.00
```

**I would like to show the other departments also with zeros**

```
NAme    EngHours    EngRate EngDollars  DesignHours DesignRate  DesignDollars   TotalHours  TotalRate   TotalDollars    Travel  Equipment   Subcontract Other   Markups EstimateTotal
Architechtural  81  110.73  8947    237 78.85   18711   318.1   86.95   27658   0   0   0   0   0   27658
Concrete    3014    423.72  1277092 2136    357.96  764603  5150    396.45  2041695 60  45  0   325 0   2042125
Structural  903 104.98  94744   1351    0   0   2253    42.05   94744   0   0   0   0   0   94744
Mechanical  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Piping  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Process 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Civil   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Electrical  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Project Admin   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
C&A 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Estimating  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Procurement 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: I dont see any question. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: Probably a good idea if you simplify your query to a minimized version that still displays the issue.

Comment: @Juan Carlos Oropeza - Question is in the title which brought you here in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the Activity and Activity_Details tables do not have any data for those departments.  You should make them and any other table without data for all departments be connected as left joins.

You can run the subquery labeled T on a standalone basis and make sure that all your departments are on the list.  Without knowing the table structure, you might have to reorder the tables in the subquery T to make "Discipline" come first, then left join everything else that is not guaranteed to have info on all departments

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Left Join works great and i did have to reorder the tables.